# As part of JMeter WEB DRIVER(Selenium Scripts) Integration With Azure Pipeline but Application is not running at Azure Pipeline

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jmeter-plugins, continuous-integration, azure-devops, cicd

Pushed the JMeter Selenium Scripts into Azure GIT Repository, created the pipeline and run the pipeline.

Agents added are: JMeter, Command Line, Publish pipeline artifact and publish and download artifacts from Release pipelines.
[image]

In the scripts the JSR223 **Sampler, counters and Chrome Driver Config** are added and after execution of test html file also generated but observed **no transactions are happening**.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Could anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

JMeter test produces some output even if it fails so in order to determine the reason of unexpected behaviour take a look at:

1. Your pipeline [console output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72433737/azure-pipelines-where-is-the-output-of-my-script)
2. JMeter [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles)
3. [jmeter.log file](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-logging)

My expectation is that your Thread Group doesn't start because [ChromeDriver](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/) binary doesn't exist at the given location. So you will need to download and unpack it. The same applies to [Chromium](https://www.chromium.org/chromium-projects/) browser itself

Comment: Thanks Drimiti, Could you please also help me on how to keep the chrome driver.exe in the project and make the path dynamic so I can run it on Azure Pipeline.